# Json mapping non standard interface

Tags: java, jackson, restful-url

I got a response which is a map of objects but they all have the same key:

```
{
    "hits": [
    {
      "recipe": {
          "id" : "0",
          "label" : "chicken noodles",
          ...
      },
      "another_field": "value"
    },
     {
      "recipe": {
          "id" : "1",
          "label" : "fried chicken",
          ...
      },
      "another_field": "value"
    },
     { "recipe": {...}, ... }
    ]
}
```

My Pojo:

```
public class SearchRecipeResponse {

    private List<RecipeResponse> hits;

    public List<RecipeResponse> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }
}
```

```
public class RecipeResponse{
    private String label;
    ...
    getters, etc
}
```

The result comes up as a list of objects but all objects are null because the json payload has this key "recipe".

Comment: it's not a map it is a list of recipe object and also please explain your question more what is use-case ? How it impact if it is a list in place of map ? or don't have unique keys ?

Comment: It is not quite a list of objects. A list of objects would be : [ {}, {}, {} ].  This is more like [ "key": {} , "key": {}, "key": {}]

Comment: `hits` a list of `recipe` objects in your json. You also need to add json annotations to your classes to map RecipeResponse to recipe or rename the response class to just Recipe.

Comment: As per the current JSON structure you will be getting something like List<hits> => Map<String,recipeObj> but as you mentioned you are getting the same keys so you can bundle them and create a list of those corresponding to the key.

Comment: The example has an error in it, one of the `{` is never closed. Not sure if that's causing the problem or just a typo.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz the code here may have a typo but the response is correct. I've edited it

Comment: I think there's an object between hits and recipe which I have to map

Answer (score 0):

You can create an POJO for the recipe and use that for the mapping. Not sure though that's what you want to do, you need to expand your question to add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted by adding an extra mapping to each object. My mapping was wrong. Thank you for the answers.

```
public class SearchRecipeResponse {

    private List<HitResponse> hits;

    public List<HitResponse> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }
}
```

```
public class HitResponse{
    private RecipeResponse recipe;
    ...
    getters, etc
}
```

For those missing the jackson annotations I am not using them as the fields names match the properties.